# ADF fuzzy left join returns fewer rows than expected

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a dataflow in ADF in which I am using a fuzzy left outer self join to compare customer names and identify duplicates. I used a sample of the data in the source SQL (2 customers only where both names match 100%). On testing, the regular left join where AccountName == AccountName works as expected and returns 4 records because both names match.

However, when using fuzzy left outer join at 65% match threshold, only 2 of the 4 records are returned. The expectation is that each join would result in the same 4 records.

How does this need to be setup for the fuzzy join to return the same number of records for this sample if I am doing this correctly? I suspect this is a bug with the fuzzy left outer join in ADF.

Here is the data:

| Acct_Id | AcctName |
| --- | --- |
| 5799930 | RENTAL SERVICE |
| 5799940 | RENTAL SERVICE |

**Flow:**
[image: Flow]

**LeftOuter join results:**
[image]

**FuzzyLeft join results:**
[image: FuzzyLeft join results]

**LeftOuter join conditions**
[image: LeftOuter join conditions]

**FuzzyLeft join conditions**
[image: FuzzyLeft join conditions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried the same I have 2 records in left table and 4 records in right table.

- When I left joined it, I got 4 records as I have duplicate records in right table as below:
  [image]
- In fuzzy joint it is returning the records with common values only as below:
  [image]

Check if you have any duplicate records or try first convert the datatype of column to string and the use it in join.

[image]

If still facing same might be issue with matching algorithm, then it's better to raise a  [Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)  for deeper investigation on this issue.

Comment: Yeah, in my join conditions I was already converting both to strings since the pipeline complained about ANY and STRING type mismatch without conversion. I'll open a ticket. Thanks for confirming my suspicion.